# How can I manually turn off edit mode when the last item in a List gets deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui, edit

I have a simple view in my app that displays a list of checklists. When there are no checklists I display a placeholder view.

**The issue I'm having is that when I delete the last item in the list, the EditButton() doesn't switch back to "Edit"; it still says "Done," even thought the list is empty** If I then add a new item, the list appears again but in edit mode (a bad UX).

Is there a way to manually "turn off" edit mode after the last item in the list gets deleted?

**Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE1yu.png

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @EnvironmentObject var checklistsVM: Store
    @StateObject var homeVM: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if(checklistsVM.checklists.isEmpty) {
                    EmptyList()
                        .environmentObject(homeVM)                    
                } else {
                    HomeListResults()
                        .environmentObject(homeVM)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Checklists", displayMode: .large)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the edit mode using the `Environment` value:

```
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Turn off edit mode") {
            editMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question it seems that manually managing `editMode` will be better for your.

You can enable manual control over the `editMode` with binding with a @State variable.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"]
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                    // Here's how you can change the editing state
                        withAnimation {
                            editMode = .inactive
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Cancel Editing")
                    })
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            editMode = .active
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Edit")
                    })
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can observe your `checklistsVM.checklists` value to check when it is empty, and then disable your Edit mode accordingly as I have done in the "Cancel Edit" button action.